# VBA Access Compile Error - Data Member Not Found - How to ignore?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, compiler-errors

I have the code below in a button in my forms in MS Access. The problem is that sometimes not all "strCTRL"s exist. In some forms they do, in some they don't. The whole code is 900+ lines long so I won't post all of it. It's a SQL query which references controls and extracts their value.

The problem comes when not all controls are present, then I get the error: Compile error: Method or data Member not found.

Is there a way to bypass the compile error or tell VBA to compile it only if it exists? I tried `If...Nothing` and `On Error Resume Next`, but they don't seem to work. There's also other objects that will not exist on each page, not just the ones below. So...any ideas? =/

```
Dim strCTRL1 As String
Dim strCTRL2 As String
Dim strCTRL3 As String
Dim strCTRL4 As String
Dim strCTRL5 As String
Dim strCTRL6 As String
Dim strCTRL7 As String
Dim strCTRL8 As String
Dim strCTRL9 As String
Dim strCTRL10 As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
On Error Resume Next
strCTRL1 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Text684.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL2 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Label2210.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL3 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Label2295.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL4 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Label73.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL5 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Label160.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL6 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Label246.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL7 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Label332.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL8 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Label417.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL9 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Label506.DefaultValue & " "
strCTRL10 = "[Control Number] = " & Me.Text2285.DefaultValue & " "
```

Comment: Labels don't have a `.DefaultValue` property, this may be an additional cause of errors.

Comment: They're not labels, they're converted Text Boxes...don't ask lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array or list of the label names, then:

```
Dim LabelName As String
Dim LabelNames As Variant

LabelNames = Array("Text684", "Label2210", ...etc.)
' ...
LabelName = LabelNames(1)
strCTRL1 = "[Control Number] = " & Me(LabelName).DefaultValue & " "
```

That will compile, though - of course - fail at runtime for non-existing labels.

Comment: Still gives the same error when I use arrays =/ Any other ideas?

Comment: Well - you must, of course, either dim the array or create it as a _Variant_ using `Array` for the code to compile.

Comment: I tried Dim-ing it and it didn't work. I don't know how to create it as a Variant though. How would what you purposed help with the LabelName/String etc?

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Additionally, I made another version where the unneeded sheets/controls are hidden. The macro loops through them and finds them, but they aren't visible :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to @Gustav, you got your code to compile, and his suggestions, combined with `On Error Resume Next` will get your code to run without errors under any circumstance.

But there is no way to tell if your code is correct, because now, the compiler won't tell you which controls are misnamed or missing.

So instead, I would suggest an array-based approach like this:

```
    Dim Ctl As Access.Control
    Dim CtlValues() As String 
    Dim i as Long

    i = 0
    ReDim CtlValues 1 To Me.Controls.Count 

    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        If Ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            i = i + 1
            CtlValues(i) = "[Control Number] = " & CStr(Nz(Ctl.DefaultValue, "Null"))
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve CtlValues 1 To i
```

These 12 lines of code perform the same task that the 900 lines do (going by your example). This code will work in any form, regardless of how many controls there are, and what they are named. This code is way easier to understand and work with.

See if maybe an approach like this will work here.

Comment: This is something that I wished to do, but can't work unfortunately as only 12-13 out of the 20 text boxes on each pages are handled in this manner, and they have different names on each page, with a different control number text box reference on each page. This gives me good ideas for future use, though :) Thank you too!